# PHPSTORM_META how to specify return type

Tags: php, phpstorm

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#navigate-to-a-metadata-directive

There is a custom DI (legacy) that works like this:

```php
/** @var SomeClass $settings */  
$settings = DI()->GetSettings(SomeClass::NAME);

$settings instanceof SomeClass = true
SomeClass::NAME - constant, exists in every class
```

How to specify in `.phpstorm.meta.php` that something that ends in `::NAME` should be returned as a value?

```php
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META
{
    override(DI()->GetSettings(0'::NAME'), type(0));
}
```

Comment: I've never mastered PhpStorm metadata, but I made the mistake of thinking you can type arbitrary PHP code, given that you have a `.php` file. In fact, it's more like a settings file. Only a few elements are supported. So I suspect that `DI()->GetSettings(0'::NAME')` is ignored. Have you tried something like `DI::GetSettings(0)`? (I'm not saying it'll work, just guessing.)

Comment: 1) You are `PHPSTORM_META` **namespace** therefore you should use FQN for all classes. Right now your `DI()` is treated as `PHPSTORM_META\DI` . 2) `DI()->GetSettings` -- as Álvaro González said, hat's not a 100% real PHP file, so you cannot use `->` here. 3) `DI()` appears to be a function call. Metadata works with **types / classes** so it should be what type your `DI()` returns (I would guess it's an instance of `\DI` class perhaps). So it should be something like `\DI::GetSettings(0)`

Comment: 4) *"something that ends in `::NAME` should be returned as a value". I do not think you could do that. I mean your `(0'::NAME')` idea. 5) It sounds like your `SomeClass::NAME` is the same as PHP's native `SomeClass::class`, right? TBH I'm not super sure how (and if at all) PhpStorm can handle such a `::class` alias.

Comment: 6) I would possibly just hardcode all return types with using `map()` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#map -- this kind of approach: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#passing-a-class-constant

Comment: Actually for #5 -- you can look at using `map(['' => '@Class'])` (assuming that your `::NAME` contains a FQN (just as `::class` does) AND you are only passing `::NAME` to `GetSettings`  . If it's not proper FQN (does not have the leading ` \\` ) then perhaps `'\@Class'` will work?... have not tried, just a thought.